# How to make a redux connected react component listen to actions dispatched outside of react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got an actions file

```
import keyMirror from 'keymirror';

export const actionTypes = keyMirror({
 OPEN_LIGHTBOX: null,
 CLOSED_LIGHTBOX: null
});

export const openLightbox = (closable = false) => ({
 type: 'OPEN_LIGHTBOX',
 payload: {lightboxOpen: true, lightboxClosable: closable}
});
```

and a reducer, I'm not going to put the code in here because it doesn't seem necessary. It is at any rate working.

I have a react component that says

```
module.exports = connect((state) => {
    console.log('state change'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    console.log(state); // eslint-disable-line no-console
    return {
      findShopDomainData: state.findShopDomain
    }
  })(Autocomplete);
```

I can register state changes inside of the react component, I get the console log statements.

But I also have stuff outside of react that needs to call these redux actions. So I import into a JS file.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { findShopDomain } from 'path to reducer file happens here'
import { openLightbox } from  'path to action file'
```

then I

```
let reduxStore = createStore(findShopDomain);
reduxStore.dispatch(openLightbox(true));
```

If I do that action in my vanilla js file I get to the reducer, but the state change is never registered in my connected React Component. I'm supposing it's because the connect function probably turns it into a new reducer, and in essence I actually have two reducers siting around that won't be affecting each other.

At any rate I would really like some way to have reduxStore.dispatch(openLightbox(true)); in my vanilla js be registered by my react component.

Comment: actually I figured out why it was not being added, basically we had a store.js that was being passed in as a prop to our components in a very roundabout way I can't clarify in this comment. So of course I just had to require that store.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using global scope
`window.store = createStore(findShopDomain);
window.store.dispatch(openLightbox(true))`